# QSqlTableModel inserting new record, getting data is QVariant(invalid)

Tags: qt, qvariant, qsqltablemodel

I have a simple QSqlTableModel:

```
class UsersModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UsersModel();
    ~UsersModel();

    bool newUser(const QString &name, const QString &surname, const QString &birthday);
};

UsersModel::UsersModel()
{
    setTable("users");
    select();
}
```

When I'm inserting a new record into the model, it is inserted into the database, but immediate retrieving of this record from the model doesn't work:

```
bool UsersModel::newUser(const QString &name, const QString &surname, const QString &birthday)
{
    QSqlRecord rec = record();
    rec.setGenerated("id", true);
    rec.setValue("name", QVariant(name));
    rec.setValue("surname", QVariant(surname));
    rec.setValue("birthday", QVariant(birthday));

    bool res = insertRecord(-1, rec);
    if (res) {
        qDebug() << "last inserted id:" << query().lastInsertId();
        qDebug() << "name: " << record(rowCount() - 1).value("name");
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Result of newUser method call:**

last inserted id: QVariant(qlonglong, 31)
name:  QVariant(Invalid)

If I look into the database, record is inserted, but if I try to get it from the model, invalid QVariant is returned.
What I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't the model return data for the newly inserted record?

Comment: What is the edit strategy of your model? Try to set it to `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange` and check the result.

Comment: Are you assuming that `query().lastInsertId()` is the same is `rowCount() - 1`? It's not always so.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov
According to the docs: `QSqlRecord QSqlQueryModel::record ( int row ) const`  Returns the record containing information about the fields of the current query.  If row is the index of a valid row, the record will be populated with values from that row. -- I assume that the inserted record is the last one in the model, therefore `rowCount() - 1` should be the index of the last row. -- Could be that it's wrong assumption, but again according to the doc `insertRecord(-1, rec)` should append the row to in the model.

Comment: New entry may appear in the middle of the table depending on your model's sort settings.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Hmm..ok, but still `record(rowCount() - 1).value("name")` should return last record from the model, regardless of the id of that record. It is model's responsibility to return correct number of rows in `rowCount()` method.